# Kotlin 1.1.1 vs 1.2.30 & AspectJ

Tags: kotlin, aspectj

I am trying to use Kotlin 1.2.30 with AspectJ (using the following AspectJ gradle plugin: [github repo](https://github.com/sedovalx/gradle-aspectj-binary), no affiliation with the author). My build gradle seems to work with older versions of kotlin (e.g. 1.1.1), but not with 1.2 versions.

I am trying to add aspects to the following *Main.kt* file:

```
package test

fun main (args: Array<String>) {
    object  {
        fun foo () { print("foo")}
    }.foo()
}
```

My aspect file, *AspectTest.kt* is as follows:

```
package test

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect

@Aspect
class AspectTest {

    @Around("execution (* *())")
    fun around(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint) : Any? {
            println("joinpoint")
            return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

My *build.gradle* is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.github.sedovalx.gradle:gradle-aspectj-binary:1.0.25"
    }
}


group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.sedovalx.gradle-aspectj-binary'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile ("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.1")
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

mainClassName ='test.MainKt'

weaveClasses.dependsOn compileJava
classes.dependsOn weaveClasses
```

When I run the code using `kotlin_version = 1.1.1` it works and prints:

> joinpoint
>
> foo

In case of Kotlin 1.2.30 (or any other in 1.2 branch I tried) "foo" is printed, as if the aspect did not work.

How can I remedy the problem in case of newer kotlin versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that kotlin 1.1.1 puts kotlin classes to `build/classes/java` while kotlin 1.2.30 compiles .class files to `build/classes/kotlin`. The AspectJ [gradle plugin](https://github.com/sedovalx/gradle-aspectj-binary) I used reads .class files for weaving from `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` directory, which by default is set to `build/classes/java` and there are no files in my project there. I think plugin author should change its code to use `sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs` instead, which allows for many .class output directories, what is especially important in polyglot project.

Nevertheless I adressed the problem with 1.2.30 kotlin incompatibility in a hacky way by adding `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir=sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.toString().replace("java", "kotlin")` line to my `build.gradle`

Comment: could you show your updated build.gradle file please?

Comment: @Anton I just added the following line at the end of build.gradle: `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir=sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.toString().replace("java", "kotlin")`

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to gradle, but I think you should be able to make this work with gradle as well. I've made a sample project using kotlin (1.3.40) + aspectj (1.9.1) + maven (with two different plugins that simplify weaving for maven builds, both seem to be working fine). You can check it out here: https://github.com/serpro69/kotlin-aspectj-maven-example